# Do we ever need irrational coefficients to generate a rational?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules

Three easier warm-up questions and then The Real Question...

**Question 1:** Do there exist numbers $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb Q$ such that in order to have $pr=q$ we must have that $r$ is irrational?

**Answer to Question 1: No.**  Either $p=q=0$, in which case $r$ can be anything, or $q\neq0$, in which case $r=\frac qp$ is the only solution, and this is rational.

**Question 2:** Do there exist polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ such that in order to have $p(x)r(x)=q(x)$ we must have that $r(x)$ has at least one irrational coefficient?

**Answer to Question 2: No.** Actually, given that $q(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ is nonzero, it is not possible for $q(x)$ to be expressed as the product of $p(x)$ and some polynomial $r(x)$ unless $r(x)$ has strictly rational coefficients.  This is less obvious than the situation with the previous question.

**Question 3:** Do there exist polynomials $p_1(x),\ldots,p_k(x)$ and $q(x)$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ such that in order to have
$$p_1(x)r_1(x)+\cdots +p_k(x)r_k(x) = q(x)$$
at least one of $r_1(x),\ldots,r_k(x)$ must have at least one irrational coefficient?

That is, $q(x)$ has rational coefficients, and can be expressed as a linear combination of some specific other polynomials that have rational coefficients, but *only* by multiplying them by some polynomials that do *not* have rational coefficients.

Is such a situation possible?

This is the same as asking: Is it possible to start with polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$, allow them to generate an ideal in $\mathbb R[x]$, and then find within that ideal some polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$ which would not have appeared had the ideal been generated over $\mathbb Q[x]$ instead?

Perhaps the first two warm-up questions were misleading; in each of those cases, we rule out the multiplier being irrational altogether.  That is, we show that only a rational multiplier is possible.  But in the third question, certainly it is possible that the multipliers $r_i(x)$ could live outside of $\mathbb Q[x]$.  The question is, can some choice of the $p_i(x)$ and $q(x)$ ever *force* that to happen?

**Note:** This has already been pointed out in the comments, so I might as well acknowledge it: For the sake of simplicity, I am intentionally neglecting instances like $p=0$ and $q=1$ (in Question 1) or $p(x)=x^2$ and $q(x)=x$ (in Question 2) in which the condition is impossible and therefore (technically/vacuously) implies anything.

**Answer to Question 3: (added later)** I think I can answer Question 3.  Consider the ideal generated by the $p_i(x)$ in $\mathbb R[x]$.  Since $\mathbb R[x]$ is a PID, this ideal is principal.  Now I think it suffices (by Question 2, actually) to show that the generator of this ideal can be taken in $\mathbb Q[x]$.  But the most natural generator is the $\rm gcd$ of all the polynomials $p_i(x)$, and this is in fact in $\mathbb Q[x]$.  So every polynomial in this ideal is a multiple of this generator, which is rational, and hence by Question 2 every rational polynomial in the ideal is a rational multiple of the generator, and hence has to be in the ideal that the $p_i(x)$ would generate over $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Since I have (I think) answered Question 3, let me move on to...

**The Real Question:** If in Question 3 we replace $\mathbb Q[x]$ and $\mathbb R[x]$ by $\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$ and $\mathbb R[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$, does that change the answer?

Comment: I think (2) is "Yes". Take $q = x$ and $p = x^2$

Comment: @mathworker21 Non-existent polynomials don't have irrational coefficients. Or they can have any coefficients you want, depending on how you interpret a non-existent object "having" something.

Comment: Polynomials over a field form a principal ideal domain, so doesn't the $k$ polynomials question reduce to the $1$ polynomial question already solved?

Comment: Ah, we came to the same conclusion, a few seconds apart.

Comment: Sorry about that!  Let me say I appreciate your interest.  Since in the multivariate case we don’t have a PID, I am a little stuck with that one.

Comment: Hint: replace the $f_i$ by a Gröbner basis of the ideal they generate.

Comment: @Ben Oh, I like that hint.  I know that such a Gröbner basis can be taken with rational coefficients.  (Its computation is agnostic to what ring we claim to be working in, I guess.)  If I consider a reduced Gröbner basis, I can even say that the representation with respect to the basis is unique, which feels like it should be useful somehow...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, but the ring extension $\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_k]\subset\mathbb R[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$ is faithfully flat, and thus $I\mathbb R[x_1,\ldots,x_k]\cap\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_k]=I$ for every ideal $I\subset\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments give hints to solutions using commutative algebra. Here's a solution using only linear algebra:

consider a complement $\mathbb Q$-vector space $\mathbb Q\oplus S = \mathbb R$.

Then $\mathbb R[x_1,...,x_n] = \mathbb Q[x_1,...,x_n]\oplus S[x_1,...,x_n]$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces. Now this is a complement of $\mathbb Q[x_1,...,x_n]$  that is stable under each endomorphism $p\mapsto x_ip$. Call this endomorphism $\varphi_i$

If we write $\sum_i r_ip_i = \sum_i p_i(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n)(r_i)$, then the equality $\sum_i r_ip_i = q$ rewrites as $\sum_i p_i(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n)(r_i) = q$.

We may now mod out by $S[x_1,...,x_n]$ to get $\sum_i p_i(\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n)(\overline{r_i}) = q$ where $\overline{r_i}\in \mathbb Q[x_1,...,x_n]$, which itself rewrites as $\sum_i \overline{r_i}p_i = q$ in $\mathbb Q[x_1,...,x_n]$ : we are done.