# Generating irrational numbers with rational coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, irrational-numbers

For some positive integer $n$, let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be positive real numbers. Consider the set of all linear combinations of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with nonnegative, **rational** coefficients:

$$ LC= \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n q_i x_i \; : \; q_i \in \mathbb{Q} \cap[0, \infty) \right\}$$

For any finite sequence of positive real numbers $(x_1, \dots, x_n$), I think there is always an irrational number $r$ such that $r \notin LC$. Moreover, this unattainable irrational number can be made arbitrarily large. How does one prove this?

---

[Do we ever need irrational coefficients to generate a rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359678/do-we-ever-need-irrational-coefficients-to-generate-a-rational) <-- this might answer my question, but I do not understand it, and I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

The question can be reformulated: let $f : \mathbb{Q^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of the form $f = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i q_i$ for $\lambda_i \in [0, \infty)$ and variables $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ (this is slightly more general), $i = 1, \dots, n$. Then there exist arbitrarily large values $r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r \notin f(\mathbb{Q}^n)$.

Comment: What do you know of cardinality?

Comment: Two sets have the same cardinality when there is a bijection between them. Countable sets have the same cardinality as some subset of the natural numbers. $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, whereas $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable (thus $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable). So there cannot be a surjection from $\mathbb{Q}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $LC \cup \mathbb Q$ is countable, $[N, \infty)$ is not...